# How to find lowest value from one columns that has been Grouped by SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for some assistance: I am looking to get this into a report but not sure how to achieve this.

Here is the data stored in the table:

```
Product  | Quantity |  Status  | Line
Product1      1        Active   1000
Product2      2        Active   2000
Product1      2        Active   3000
Product1      1        InDev    4000
Product2      2        Active   5000
```

I am grouping by `Product` and `Status` and summing up `Quantity`.

But looking to also retrieve the lowest line number for row in the group.

My expected result would be like below:

```
Product  | Quantity |  Status  | Line
Product1      3        Active    1000
Product2      4        Active    2000
Product1      1        InDev     5000
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function :

```
select *
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by product, status order by line) as seq,
             sum(qty) over (partition by product, status) as sum_qty
      from table t
      ) t
where seq = 1;
```

If table has only available columns (in question) then you can do aggregation :

```
select product, sum(qty), status, min(line) as line
from table t
group by product, status
order by line;
```

Comment: Great Thanks it's displaying correctly now, How would I then have an Order By Line asc added to display the Lowest Line number first?

Comment: @Frikkels.. . . Add `order by`.

Comment: Thanks for assisting Had to add min(line) to my order line.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done if you `group by Product, Status` and aggregate:

```
select Product, sum(Quantity) Quantity,  Status, min(Line) Line
from tablename
group by Product, Status
```